# If i have sand substrate will my good bacteria beneath the sand still get fed?

Tags: aquarium, fish, water-parameters, substrate

I just put power sand, pumice for living bacteria, then on top of it hard sand, then the toppest is full the finest granule sand. I filled the water and now wait to cycle the tank. I wonder whether the bacteria are going to be able to live and get ammonia on those power sand and pumice in the most bottom knowing that sand is tight? I build this tank for goldfish, that's why I use sand so the goldfish can forage without accidentally cuckle.

Comment: If the super fine sand is on top of the more coarse sand, you are likely inhibiting bacteria from occupying the lower layers of sand. Fine sand can block water and oxygen in just 1/2 to 1in. You might also be creating an anoxic environment below the fine sand which is generally not ideal. I don't really have a remedy for you if it's already in there, but fine sand on top of gravel or coarse sand is typically not ideal.